# Declaring data of exactly X bytes in C

Tags: c, variables

I would a to make something in C to hold exactly X bytes. What would be the best way to do that? I was thinking of using a char pointer to X number of chars, but is there a better way? Some variable type I'm unaware of?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Persisting data to a certain format is different from in-memory storage so it's important to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: There's no way for anyone else to know what you're aware of ... especially if you aren't even aware of arrays, which is the way "to make something in C hold exactly X" things of some type.

Comment: A "char" is exactly one byte.  An array `char array[1]` is also exactly one byte.  An array `char array[2]` is two bytes.  And so on.  Alternatively, `char *buffer = malloc(n_bytes)` can hold any size you want ... but you need to keep track of what that size is yourself.

Comment: My initial question wasn't phrased properly, my apologies. I want to actually initialize the variable with X bytes. I though of using char buf[X] = "X number of chars", but that would get tedious if I want to do it for say, 1000 bytes. Perhaps similar to mmap, but for a variable?

Comment: if you want to initialize your array, you can use `char myarray[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, ...}`.  For 1000 hex literals, if you wish. The result, of course, would be read-only.  Or `char myarray[10]= {'A', 'B', 'C'}` (initialize only the first 3 bytes of an N-byte read/write array).  Q: Exactly what *do* you want?

Comment: @FoggyDay: No, it wouldn't be read-only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that `X` is the number of bytes you want, simply define:

```
unsigned char buf[X];
```

Both `unsigned char` and plain `char` are by definition one byte in size, but `unsigned char` tends to be more convenient for dealing with raw data (which I presume is what you're trying to do).

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do. This is helpful for knowing what data type I want, but then how would I initialize it to X bytes? Would I just set buf equal to X number of 0's? Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my initial question. Basically, end goal is to have some variable buf that actually holds exactly X bytes.

Comment: @user3750550: It *does* hold exactly `X` bytes. The contents are initially zero if it's defined at file scope or with the `static` keyword, or garbage if it's defined at block scope (inside a function). If you want to initialize it, look up "initialization" in your C reference. If you want to ask a different question, please do so by posting a new question.

Comment: So, if I use unsigned char buf[X]; then buf actually holds X bytes. If I want 5 bytes, I don't need to do unisgned char buf[] = "00000"?

Comment: @user3750550: Right, it's capable of holding `X` bytes of whatever you care to store in it. The *size* of the array is defined when it's created. The *contents* may change over time depending on how and whether you initialize it and what you later store in it.

Comment: Note that `char buf[] = "12345"` will have *SIX* bytes.  5 characters + null terminator.